# Find what process is sending periodically 12 spaces characters on my MacBookPro M1

Tags: macos, mac

I have a MacBook Pro M1 Max 2021 with Ventura 13.4

Since an hour ago, every 28/30 seconds, 12 spaces are being sent regardless of the application I am using.

Given the regularity of the behavior (periodicity and sent keys), I believe it is a software issue. I tried starting a guest session to see if the problem was related to my session. The problem also exists in the guest session.

I don't know how to identify the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the source of the problem, but I upgraded to Sonoma 14.1, and it disappeared.